# WSO2 ESB about dbreport and performance

Tags: wso2, loops, wso2-esb

I have a testing in WSO2 ESB dbreport mediator.
When I send a "BIG message" (100 or 1,000 or 10,000 ... 500,000 rows) from Database A to WSO2 ESB.
And WSO2 ESB split the message as rows by Iterate mediators,
then use the DBReport mediator write row by row into Database B (by Data source pool).

When write 100 rows, it spent 5 seconds, 
when write 1,000 rows, it spent 188 seconds,
and then write 10,000 rows, it need spent 19163 seconds.

How efficient use of DBReport mediators?

thanks.

Comment: below is my configuration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBReport mediator is executed synchronously in WSO2 ESB which means the thread that execute this DBReport mediator is stucked until the Database operation is completed. That means the performance is lower than when the execution happens asynchronously.

Therefore to gain the maximum performance, please use WSO2 Data Services server and use DSS to execute the insert Database operation. That way you can gain the maximum performance.

Comment: Hi Harshana，
 Thanks your answer.

 I have try to test insert data into RDBMS from WSO2 ESB through WSO2 DSS, but have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: In order to implement that, you need to generate the message that you want to send to DSS inside ESB. For that you can use "PayloadFactory" mediator or "Enrich" mediator. Once you have generated the Request to be sent to DSS from ESB, you can use "Send" mediator to send the generated message to the DSS server. For that you can add an "Address Endpoint" to the Send mediator. Please follow the http://blog.afkham.org/2012/05/wso2-esb-service-chaining.html article and http://blog.afkham.org/2012/05/scatter-gather-eip-with-wso2-esb.html to get a better understanding.

Comment: You can implement your ESB messaging flows as well as DSS configurations with WSO2 Developer Studio. You can download it from http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio location. It will help you to learn WSO2 suite quickly. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Harshana, Thanks again.
I was created a WSO2 ESB proxy service, it be receive SOAP message that contain rows data, and use Iterate mediator split as data row by row. Then send row data to WSO2 DSS.
WSO2 DSS write the data into RDBMS table.

The WSO2 ESB proxy service content in next comment....

Comment: <inSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" continueParent="true" expression="//LD_REPORT_HIS_record" id="Iter_rcd" sequential="false">
      <target>
         <sequence>
            <send>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="http://172.16.1.111:9765/services/test/" />
               </endpoint>
            </send>
         </sequence>
      </target>
   </iterate>
.
.
.
.
</inSequence>

Comment: WSO2 DSS configuration is ...
<data name="test" enableBatchRequests="true">
   <config id="TEMP_DB_esb_test">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">TEMP_DB_esb_test</property>
   </config>
   <query id="INS_LD" useConfig="TEMP_DB_esb_test">
      <sql>insert into ld_report_his (emfact_nm, document_nm, history_time) values (:emfact_nm,:document_nm,to_date(:history_time,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))</sql>
      <param name="emfact_nm" . . .
   </query>
   <operation name="op1">
      <call-query href="INS_LD">
         <with-param name=" . . .
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>

Comment: But, it is not work!

It has the error message in WSO2 ESB and WSO2 DSS :
ERROR - AxisEngine The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/test and the WSA Action = null


I can not fixed the error.

Comment: Are you sure you have provided the correct endpoint URL for the data service? As i can see in the configuration it is <address uri="172.16.1.111:9765/services/test/"; />  which is wrong. It should be <address uri="http://172.16.1.111:9765/services/test/" /> Please try with that change.

Comment: Hi, Harshana,

It's maybe the "stackoverflow" system bug.
When I post content in edit field, it is no semicolon. But when I click "Add Comment" button and complete post comment, the semicolon was appear.

So, the URI is correct. I was tried the WSO2 DSS service by "try it" successful.

Comment: Ok. I think the reason is that you are sending an incorrect request to your Data Service. Before sending the request using Send mediator you need to construct the message with Payload Factory. So if you could attach your Data Service Request you have tried with try-it tool, i can help you with the ESB configurations.